# How do I reorganize Items Title View?

Tags: list, list-view

How do I order the titles for my List Views? In below screen shot, I want "All Documents" to be before "ELearning."

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Click on the `All Documents` View
- From the above ribbon > select `Modify view`

[image]

- Check `Make this default view` > Click Ok.

[image]

It's should be now before `Elearning` view

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I accidentally made the ELearning title the new default title.